# form validation on change blur and submit of form and fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
// App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import fields from './fields'
import CustomInputType from './custominputtype'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    formData: {},
    fieldErrorStatus: {},
    submitErrorStatus: false
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    // adding the new on change value to the corresponding field name
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const tempObj = { ...this.state.formData };
    tempObj[name] = value;
    this.setState({ formData: tempObj });

    // adding the error status for the corresponding field name
    let tempErrorStatus = { ...this.state.fieldErrorStatus }
    tempErrorStatus[name] = false;
    this.setState({ fieldErrorStatus: tempErrorStatus })

  };


  handleSubmit = (e) => {

    let formValues = this.state.formData;

    if (Object.keys(formValues).length === 0) {
      this.setState({ submitErrorStatus: true })
    }
    else {
      let tempErrorStatus = {};

      this.setState({ submitErrorStatus: false });
      Object.keys(formValues).forEach(key => {
        if (formValues[key]) {
          tempErrorStatus[key] = false;
        }
      })
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          fieldErrorStatus: { ...prevState.fieldErrorStatus, tempErrorStatus }
        }
      })
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form">
        <form
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
        >
          <div className="inputs-collection">
            {
              fields[0].attributes.map((field, i) => {
                return (
                  <CustomInputType
                    attributes={field}
                    key={i}
                    value={this.state.formData[i]}
                    obj={this.state.formData}
                    errorStatus={this.state.fieldErrorStatus}
                    displayError={this.state.submitErrorStatus}
                  />
                )
              })
            }
          </div>
          <div className="button-container">
            <button className="submit-button" type="submit">Submit Details</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;














// CustomInputType

import React , {Component} from 'react'

class CustomInputType extends Component {
render(){
    const {
        attributes: {
            id,
            name,
            dataType,
        } = {},
        displayError,
        obj,
        errorStatus
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="input-container">
            <label htmlFor={id}>
                {name}
            </label>
            <input
                type={dataType}
                name={name || ''}
                value={obj[name]}
                id={id}
            />
            {
                displayError || Boolean(errorStatus[name]) ? 
                <span>{`Error on ${name}`}</span> : null
            }
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default CustomInputType



// fields


let fields  = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Form 1",
      "type": "Dynamic Form",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "First Name",
          "dataType": "String",
          "id": 101,
        },
        {
          "name": "Surname",
          "dataType": "String",
          "id": 102,
        },
        {
          "name": "Phone Number",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "id": 103,
        },
        {
          "name": "Roll Number",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "id": 104,
        }
    ]
    }
];
export default fields;
```

i have a parent component , where i am reading a json file locally and rendering the fields, basically i have a child component which is  a custom input type component.

in my child component there is an prop called error it is a boolean value. So if it is true it will show a red box around the field. The cases i need to show the red box are onChange , onBlur and submit.
for sumbit i am using submitErrorStatus variable in state, and for handleChange and onBlur using fieldErrorStatus. So when the user directly submit without any fields entering redbox should come, once he types each field or blur the redbox should go.

i have done the below but some where it is confusing.

Parent Component

```
state = { 
      formData : {},
      fieldErrorStatus : {},
      submitErrorStatus : false
    }

 handleChange = (e) => {
        // adding the new on change value to the corresponding field name
        const { name, value} = e.target;
        const tempObj = {...this.state.formData};
        tempObj[name] = value;
        this.setState({ formData:tempObj });

        // adding the error status for the corresponding field name
        let tempErrorStatus = {...this.state.fieldErrorStatus}
        tempErrorStatus[name] = false;
        this.setState({fieldErrorStatus:tempErrorStatus})

    };


handleSubmit = (e) => {

        let formValues = this.state.formData;

        if(Object.keys(formValues).length === 0){
            this.setState({submitErrorStatus: true})
        }
        else{
            let tempErrorStatus = {};

            this.setState({submitErrorStatus: false});
            Object.keys(formValues).forEach(key => {
                if(formValues[key]){
                    tempErrorStatus[key] = false;
                }
            })
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {
                    fieldErrorStatus: {...prevState.fieldErrorStatus, tempErrorStatus}
                }
            })
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render(){
      <div className = "form">
                        <form 
                            onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} 
                            onChange = {(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                            >
                            <div className = "inputs-collection">
                            {
                                fields.map((field, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <InputTypes 
                                            attributes = {field} 
                                            key = {i}                                 
                                            value = {this.state.formData[i]}
                                            obj = {this.state.formData}
                                            errorStatus = {this.state.fieldErrorStatus}
                                            displayError = {this.state.submitErrorStatus}
                                        />
                                    )                                                            
                                })
                            }
                            </div>
                            <div className = "button-container">
                                <button  className = "submit-button" type = "submit">Submit Details</button>
                            </div>
                        </form> 
                    </div> 

}
```

Child Component

```
render(){
   const {
            attributes : {
                id,
                name,
                dataType,
                rules,            
            } = {}, 
            displayError,
            obj,
            errorStatus
        } = this.props;

 return(
 <div className="input-container">

                <Input 
                    type = {dataType} 
                    id = {id.toString()}
                    name = {name || ''}
                    value = {obj[name]}
                    error={displayError || errorStatus[name] ? false : true} />



            </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Uhm.. what exactly is your question? "It just doesn't work"? :D

Comment: no i have a json file, where i get a field list collection which i get in the parent component , using a map method i will pass the attributes, errorStatus to the child component

Comment: so when user is clicking on submit without entering the details , red border will show to each fields , once value is there the red border will go , also when the user made a onBlur in any input field and go to next field without entering any data red border should come

Comment: @Elias the problem is its a dynamic list, and this much conditions i should satisfy any idea

Comment: I'll start a project and throw the components in and see what I can do.

Comment: @Elias thank you for the help

Comment: @Elias Submit : every input should have a min 1 char or value if not show error message to each field
blur: on blur if field is empty should show error message to that particular field
onChange: when nothing is entered and moved to next field show error message to that particular field

Comment: I'm getting `Line 57:  'fields' is not defined  no-undef` can you provide me the array?

Comment: fields is a json data, it is a collection of fields. Will post it in the question

Comment: @Elias posted the implemented code in the question. Can you check that

Comment: @Elias please let me know if you are facing any other issue

Comment: Well, you're importing the file.. I need (or at least some elements of) that file to test it

Comment: @Elias posted in the question, can you check the question

Comment: `import fields from './fields'` is that your json file? I need that :D

Comment: posted in the question, already . Fields.js

Comment: expand the code snippet and scroll down you will see the Fields.js, direclty you can paste three files, Fields.js, App.js and custominputtype.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187117/discussion-between-elias-and-dileep-thomas).

Comment: @Elias are you able to run the code

Comment: Mh.. It's quite hard... I'm going to write an example that you can use as a reference :)

Comment: @Elias yeah i know its tough, sure.

Answer (score 0):

So I made you some basic components which you can use as a reference. I've implemented the `onChange` and `onBlur` method. I also made an easily accessible error message but I didn't create the `onSubmit` functions as you just have to map the array while comparing for empty inputs.

Here is my code:

Container:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Field from './Field';

export default class Container extends Component {
  state = {
    // Create fields
    fields: [
      { key: "0", errorMessage: 'Error message for field: 0', isValid: true },
      { key: "1", errorMessage: 'Error message for field: 1', isValid: true },
      { key: "2", errorMessage: 'Error message for field: 2', isValid: true },
      { key: "3", errorMessage: 'Error message for field: 3', isValid: true },
      { key: "4", errorMessage: 'Error message for field: 4', isValid: true }
    ]
  }
  
  render() {
    return this.state.fields.map((field, i) => {
      return <Field 
        key={field.key}
        isValid={field.isValid}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        index={i}
      />
    });
  }

  onInputChange = (index, event) => {
    let newState = this.state;
    if(event.target.value === '') {
      // Set field invalid
      newState.fields[index].isValid = false;
      // In this case log but you could do other stuff with the message
      console.log(this.state.fields[index].errorMessage);
    } else {
      // Set field valid
      newState.fields[index].isValid = true;
    } 

    this.setState(newState);
  }
}
```

Input:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Field extends Component {
  render() {
    // Get props
    const {isValid, onChange, index} = this.props;

    return <input 
      type="text"
      // Check the input
      onInput={event => onChange(index, event)}
      onBlur={event => onChange(index, event)}
      // If invalid make the background red
      style={{backgroundColor: isValid ? 'white' : 'red'}}
    />
  }
}
```

I hope it helps =)

Comment: Thanks for the help ,little bit confused

Comment: I'm sorry I sadly don't have time to create the complete thing but I'm sure you'll see what I did. BTW if you leave a field empty it will (at this point log to the console) show the error message.

Comment: will check and let you know

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will revert back once i check and try to implement

Comment: but onSubmit i will have empty object then how i will check that one

Comment: I'm sure you will manage this on your own (just create one more state (besides the `errorMessage` and `isValid`) and set that to the content of the input `onChange` So you can loop through those `onSubmit` and check for empty values =)) Like I said.. I've to work, sorry.. maybe later but now today =(

Comment: but initially when user directly submitted without any handle change or blur , i can store it in another variable but after that how it can be removed

Comment: In my case: `newState.fields[index].value = event.target.value` just put that in `onChange` and they will always be the same

Comment: tried it but didnt worked with the submit, for the code that i have posted can you check whether the logic is working

Comment: i know you are busy, please check once you are free. I have implemented another logic for 80 % cases its working but some cases its failing